# How to use @protocol in AppDelegate iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, protocols

I am working in iPhone app with 5 screens. I want to refresh the values in the screen 4th in UITabBarController. I have added @protocol in AppDelegate but it is not calling. This is the first time am using @protocol could you please help me to solve this issue,

In **AppDelegate.h**

```
@protocol ReloadViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) refreshViewController:(NSString *)result;

@end

id refreshViewControllerDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) id refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

and i have synthesized.

In **AppDelegare.m**

```
@synthesize refreshViewControllerDelegate;

if ([refreshViewControllerDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReloadViewControllerDelegate)]) 
{
   [refreshViewControllerDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:) withObject:@"YES" waitUntilDone:NO];                
}// Control not come inside of if Condition.... From here i want to update the fourthViewController..
```

But `control not go inside of the if condition`. Could you please guide me where am doing wrong?

In my **4th ViewController.h**

```
#import "AppDelegate"

@interface fourthViewController : UIViewController <ReloadViewControllerDelegate>
```

In my **4th ViewController.m**

```
-(void) refreshViewController:(NSString *)result
{
    NSLog(@"Result : %@", result);
}
```

Can anyone please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `refreshViewControllerDelegate` set to your instance of `fourthViewController` ?

Comment: Did you make sure `refreshViewControllerDelegate` is not `nil`?

Comment: Sorry friends. I can't understand if you don't mind could you please correct my question. it will be help for me? thanks.

Comment: @Gopinath Where are you setting `reloadChatViewControllerDelegate` to your 4th view controller?

Comment: checking for `respondsToSelector:` is better than `conformsToProtocol:` because it should allow things as long as they implement the functionality, not necessarily needing to explicitly name the protocol in the class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are calling this code:

```
if ([refreshViewControllerDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReloadViewControllerDelegate)])
```

But `refreshViewControllerDelegate` is this:

```
id refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

`conformsToProtocol` checks to see if the object declares that it conforms to the protocol, which yours does not.  If you want to specify conformity to a protocol you need to:

```
id<ReloadViewControllerDelegate> refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

**EDIT**

OK, on the `performSelectorOnMainThread` problem...  That method is provided in a category for NSThread, and is not declared in the NSObject protocol.  So, if you want to call that, then you need to declare your type as NSObject, which conforms to your protocol.

```
NSObject<ReloadViewControllerDelegate> refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

**EDIT**

OK, it looks like this is not a simple question about using a protocol, but a full tutorial.  Since SO isn't the place for such, I'll try to give a brief one...

A protocol is an interface declaration.

```
@protocol ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)refreshViewController:(NSString *)result;
@end
```

That says there is a new protocol in town, with the name `ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate` and it also conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.  Any class that adopts the new protocol must provide an implementation of `refreshViewController`.  You can make a protocol method optional, by putting in an `@optional` section.

```
@protocol ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)refreshViewController:(NSString *)result;
@optional
- (void)optRefresh;
@end
```

Now, let's leave the adoption of the protocol for later.  Say you are writing generic code, and you just want to know if the object you are given conforms to the protocol, and if so, invoke a method on it.  Something like...

```
@interface Bar : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate>  *refreshViewControllerDelegate;
- (void)blarg;
@end
```

Now, the Bar class is providing a delegate property, so that it can be give some object that will help it do some work.  However, that delegate object must at least be an `NSObject`, and conform to the `ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

Now, ObjC (and C) is quite permissive, so you can force an object to be any type you want, but then you deserve the crash you get.  Now, when `blarg` is called, the delegate is notified to do some work.

Since the property type of the delegate already says it conforms to the given protocol, there is no need to check for conformity.  We can just call the delegate method.  Note that we must see if the object implements any optional protocol methods.

```
@implementation Bar
@synthesize refreshViewControllerDelegate = _refreshViewControllerDelegate;
- (void)blarg {
    // Do something, then invoke the delegate
    [self.refreshViewControllerDelegate
        performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:)
                         withObject:@"YES"
                      waitUntilDone:NO];
    if ([self.refreshViewControllerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(optRefresh)]) {
        [self.refreshViewControllerDelegate optRefresh];
    }
}
@end
```

However, if you want to be generic, and accept any object as a delegate (maybe you want to make it optional that the delegate conforms to some given protocol), then you can accept a plain `id` and then check to see it it conforms.  In that case, you could declare your delegate as just an id (or some other type).

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

Now, in your code, you need to check for conformity.

```
- (void)blarg {
    // Do something, then invoke the delegate
    if ([self.refreshViewControllerDelegate
            conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate)]) {
        [self.refreshViewControllerDelegate
            performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:)
                             withObject:@"YES" waitUntilDone:NO];
        if ([self.refreshViewControllerDelegate
                respondsToSelector:@selector(optRefresh)]) {
            [self.refreshViewControllerDelegate optRefresh];
        }
    }
}
```

OK, now you have a protocol defined, and you have code that calls methods on the protocol.  Two caveats.

First, the delegate has to be set to an object.  `nil` will respond `false` for any method, so it will of course not conform, nor do anything when sent any message.

Second, you have to make sure that your delegate declares conformity to the protocol.  Just implementing the methods **is not** conformity.  If a class does not explicitly specify that is conforms to a protocol, then `conformsToProtocol` will return false, even if it implements the methods of the protocol.

So, let's specify some class that will act as our delegate by conforming to the protocol.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject<ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate>
- (void)refreshViewController:(NSString *)result;
@end
@implementation Foo
- (void)refreshViewController:(NSString *)result {
    NSLog(@"Look, ma, I'm refreshed with %@", result);
}
@end
```

It conforms to the protocol, provides an implementation for the mandatory method, and omits the optional one.

Now, if you ran this code, you should see that marvelous code in all its splendor.

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
Bar *bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
bar.refreshViewControllerDelegate = foo;
[bar blarg];
```

Comment: i have tried your code but it shows warning that i have mentioned in my question. Could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the code like below and getting error. Am not familiar in iOS development. Please don't mistake me for the questions. Error message is:"Interface type cannot be statically allocated". My code is NSObject <ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate> *reloadChatViewControllerDelegate; and @property (nonatomic, retain)  NSObject <ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate> *reloadChatViewControllerDelegate;. I know this wrong but i don't know how to resolve this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but you are spinning in circles, and your issues keep changing.  Edit your original question, clean it up, and provide a complete, short, example of the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. Please help me to do this. Thanks.

Comment: "But refreshViewControllerDelegate is this" It does not matter a single bit what static type a variable has. Static object pointer types are a compile-time illusion. The actual runtime type is the only thing that matters when running the program.

Comment: "Since the property type of the delegate already says it conforms to the given protocol, there is no need to check for conformity." There is. People can still put whatever in there they want.

Comment: You may consider them compile-time illusion, but you can not ignore the warnings that the compiler gives as a result.  Thus, you should at least appease the compiler by giving it what it expects.  Also, I addressed your second comment in the text.  If you force the compiler to accept an object that does not conform -- as if it does -- then you deserve a crash at best.  If the API clearly says one thing, and you give it another, what do you expect?  This is what Apple does as well.  Try sending a mutating operation to an immutable object and you will be in exception hell immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your delegate like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<ReloadViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

The id will work, but by using the <>, you can make sure that the delegate you assign is actually implementing the protocol, you might still have to make sure it responds to selector but that is only if some methods are declared as

```
@optional
```

make sure you synthesize it and most important make sure you set it, and it is not nil.

Comment: I have tried your code but it shows warning that i have mentioned in my question. Could you please help me? I have synthesized reloadChatViewControllerDelegate. I don't know how to check whether it is null. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: The compiler has no way to know that id actually inherits from NSObject which is where that method is declared you have 2 options, instead of declaring delegate as id simply declare it as NSObject, or cast it to (NSObject *) and then call the method.

Comment: @Gopinath To get rid of the warning, either declare the delegate like `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSObject<ReloadViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;` or use a cast `[(NSObject *)refreshViewControllerDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:) withObject:@"YES" waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: @Jilouc Thanks for your response. I will try your code and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I have tried your thoughts but still the control not entering into the if condition. My code is,id reloadChatViewControllerDelegate; and @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSObject<ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate> *reloadChatViewControllerDelegate;. Please help me. Thanks..

Comment: @Gopinath Make it NSObject<ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate> reloadChatViewControllerDelegate

Comment: @OscarGomez Thanks. I have tried like this NSObject <ReloadChatViewControllerDelegate> reloadChatViewControllerDelegate; but it shows error message like "Interface type cannot be statically allocated". Could your please help me? THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a warning because you are typing your delegate as an `id`. An `id` is a generic type, which means the compiler has no idea of what methods or properties might be available. In order to remove your warning, declare your delegate to be an NSObject:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject <ReloadViewControllerDelegate> *refreshViewControllerDelegate;
```

By declaring as an NSObject, the compiler now knows about all the methods NSObject has, which will then allow you to call:

```
-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

on your delegate without warnings. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried like this you mentioned above. But the control not entering into the if condition in AppDelegate.m below code, if ([refreshViewControllerDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReloadViewControllerDelegate)]) 
{
   [refreshViewControllerDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:) withObject:@"YES" waitUntilDone:NO];                
}. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: instead of conformsToProtocol, have you tried using `respondsToSelector:`?

Comment: Still the control not entering into if conditions.

Comment: Then your controller must not be adopting the protocol correctly, or you are not setting the delegate to a class that has implemented the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@protocol ReloadViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) refreshViewController:(NSString *)result;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (weak) id <ReloadViewControllerDelegate>refreshViewControllerDelegate;
@end
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window, refreshViewControllerDelegate;

...
```

> here Tab4ViewController is name of class.

```
    if ([Tab4ViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReloadViewControllerDelegate)]) 
    {
       [refreshViewControllerDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshViewController:) withObject:@"YES" waitUntilDone:NO];                
    }

...
@end


#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Tab4ViewController<ReloadViewControllerDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation Tab4ViewController

...
appDelegate.refreshViewControllerDelegate = self;
...

@end
```