# Delegate function not called in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have written protocol in a view controller, and implement it in AppDelegate, and when I call delegate function from view controller, the delegate function is not called. Below is my code -

In class AuthenticationViewController -

```
@class AuthenticationViewController;
@protocol ApplicationTiomeoutDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addObserverForTimeout;

@end
```

And call this function using delegate -

```
[self.appTimeoutDelegate addObserverForApplicationTimeout];
```

And in AppDelegate, I have implemented this protocol like this -

```
@interface AppDelegate () <ApplicationTiomeoutDelegate>
@end
```

And then set delegate to self -

```
AuthenticationViewController *timeoutDelegate = [[AuthenticationViewController alloc] init];
[timeoutDelegate setAppTimeoutDelegate:self];
```

And implemented delegate function as well in AppDelegate, which is never called somehow -

```
-(void) addObserverForApplicationTimeout{
 // this function is never called 
}
```

I am not sure what is not correct here.

Comment: Have you loaded that `timeoutDelegate` controller in your app?

Comment: I did not get what you are asking? timeoutDelegate is instance to set self for appTimeoutDelegate and its called in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions itself.

Comment: @Richa Srivastava : First thing first. If you really wanna call a method in app delegate why do u even need a protocol ?? App delegate is a singleton instance available across all the VC's through out the app life cycle. 2. After alloc initing VC what are you doing with it ??? How is it being loaded is it your root VC ??? What I am guessing u might be initing a different instance loading a different one. Finally provide little more code for accurate answers :)

Comment: @RichaSrivastava What i'm asking is after setting delegate, have you added Controller as root controller or in navigationController?

Comment: Why this `addObserverForApplicationTimeout ` method will call? where you are set `self.appTimeoutDelegate` ? btw why you need to do this your appdelegate is already singleton.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005740/how-to-use-protocol-in-appdelegate-iphone-app

Comment: Yup, Sorry I am very new iOS Dev. There is no need of delegate as app delegate is singleton class. So i can call the method directly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppDelegate` being a *singleton* need not have the `ApplicationTiomeoutDelegate` protocol invocation. You can directly invoke `addObserverForTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

You create method in your **appdelegate**, you can directly call it wherever you want with instance of **appdelegate**.

For your question, check this below

Where are creating instance for Your delegate and where are calling your delegate form your **viewcontroller**, it is used to communicate between two class, it should have reference of protocol.

try this

Your **viewcontroller.h**

```
@protocol customDelegate;
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <customDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol customDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)method;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.delegate method];
}
```

**Your app delegate**

```
@interface AppDelegate () <customDelegate>
@end
```

Your **didfinishlaunghing**

```
viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.delegate = self;
```

and implement method:

```
-(void)method{
    NSLog(@"calling");
}
```